# tradinqview syminfo.basecurrecy

Tags: tradingview-api

How to add syminfo.basecurrecy structure as message in alarm

```
//@version=5
indicator("Indikator")
alertcondition(close[1500]<open,"Buy",message='{"BaseCurrency":"{{syminfo.basecurrency}}","Symbol": "{{ticker}}","Side":"Buy","Price":"{{close}}","Quantity":"0.05","Exchange":"{{exchange}}"}')
```

Answer (score 0):

'syminfo.basecurrency' return a string, so you can write :

```
message='{"BaseCurrency" + syminfo.basecurrency + ...
```

Comment: thanks i did as below but it gives error                                                                          
buyJson = '{"BaseCurrency":"'+ syminfo.basecurrency +'","Symbol": "{{ticker}}","Side":"Buy","Price":"{{close}}","Quantity":"0.05","Exchange":"{{exchange}}"}'
alertcondition(close[1500]<open,"Buy",message=buyJson)

Comment: of course, the rest of your message must be a string also. Try with syminfo.basecurrency only and tell me if it works